# Matplotilib, Ipython and inline plotting

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I would like to use inline plotting in the ipython notebook, i.e.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)

plot(x, x**2)
```

should show an image.

Yet I only get the following message:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: Could not create write struct
  FormatterWarning,
```

What could be the reason for this?

matplotlib==1.3.1 and ipython==2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it say anything on the terminal (i.e. the server)?

My guess is that this is most probably due to some `libpng` incompatibility issues. If you are running this on OS X, the following discussion may help:

[libpng version incompatibility in fresh installation of IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898245/libpng-version-incompatibility-in-fresh-installation-of-ipython)

Even if you aren't running OS X, similar situations may occur, if you have several copies of `libpng` floating around.