# How to make inline matplotlib graphics in ipython3 notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I tried following methods, but I always got error.
I tried:
1. Use `ipython3 notebook --matplotlib inline` in Mac console to launch iPython notebook.
Or/And 
2. Use `%matplotlib inline` in the first cell of iPython notebook.

I got this error:

> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239:
>   FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: Could not create
>   write struct
>         FormatterWarning,

I followed the solution @cel showed me (uninstall XQuartz), but I got the same error:

> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239:
>   FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: Could not create
>   write struct   FormatterWarning,

And if I execute both 1 (`ipython3 notebook --matplotlib inline`) and 2 (`%matplotlib inline`), I only got this message:

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1089fab50>
```

Additional info: 
1. OS X (10.9.5), Python 3.3.3 
2. If I use `ipython3 notebook --matplotlib=osx` to launch ipython notebook, the figure pops up in a different window (not inline).

Comment: This is question is probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898245/libpng-version-incompatibility-in-fresh-installation-of-ipython

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @cel ! I followed the instructions in the page above, and it seems I got the same error. I updated my original question.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you reinstall matplotlib after temporarily uninstalling xquartz?

Comment: Yes, I execute `pip3 install matplotlib` but it was returned that 'Requirement already satisfied'.

Comment: You didn't reinstall then. Try `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall matplotlib`