# Matplotlib inline plots in LightTable fail to appear (in Anaconda Python 2.2.0 but not 2.1.0)

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, lighttable

I'm using LightTable with the Anaconda Python distribution (for Mac). I'm trying to get the Matplotlib inline plots to appear for a simple code like the following (but with the `plt.show()` command uncommented):

```
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myplot():
  x = np.linspace(0.0, np.pi, 400)
  y = np.sin(x)
  plt.plot(x, y, lw=2, c='r')
  #plt.show()
  return(np.trapz(y,x))

myplot()
```

Upon uncommenting the `plt.show()` in the snippet above, and running `myplot()`, a white rectangle briefly appears on the screen, which then disappears.  After this, upon commenting out `plt.show()` again, the python inline evaluation in LightTable becomes inactive (except with a restart of LightTable).  Also, the connect bar shows `python` and not `ipython`, even though both python and ipython (Anaconda distribution) are on my path, and LightTable appears to be able to see them (as illustrated in the image below):
[image: LightTablePython.png]

Could it be a libpng problem (see [libpng version incompatibility in fresh installation of IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898245/libpng-version-incompatibility-in-fresh-installation-of-ipython)), or do I need to put `ipython notebook --matplotlib=inline` somewhere in the LightTable configuration?

My current version of LightTable: 0.7.2.  No issues on Ubuntu 14.04.

Update: I found a partial fix, via a reinstall of Anaconda 2.1.0 (but without any of the extra packages):

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda-2.1.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

However, a fresh re-install of Anaconda 2.2.0 did not work:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda-2.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

So obviously downgrading to Anaconda 2.1.0 is a partial fix, but in the long run, I hope to keep my packages up to date.  Could there be a problem with one of the packages (screenshot of version numbers below)?

LightTable + Anaconda 2.1.0:
[image: LightTable + Anaconda 2.1.0]

LightTable + Anaconda 2.2.0:
[image: LightTable + Anaconda 2.2.0]

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why inline matplotlib plot always has issues is that it uses the iPython matplotlib inline plot. Since iPython keeps changing and the core developer team [of LightTable] is no longer maintaining LightTable's python support this problem will keep on reappear.

> [**cldwalker commented on Nov 6, 2015**](https://github.com/LightTable/Python/issues/35#issue-115456015)
>
> The core team doesn't use Python or iPython at work and doesn't have
>   the bandwidth to look into this. Happy to take contributions from
>   anyone interested digging into this. We're also looking for a
>   maintainer for the Python plugin, ideally someone who uses it for
>   work. #31 seems like a possible solution but the contributor could use
>   a review.